# How do I listen to third party script event in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am looking to listen to an Api event in React . I tried adding the event listener in ComponentDidMount but that didn't worked

```
          MktoForms2.whenReady(function (form) {

          form.onSuccess(function () {});
```

This is an event added by [Marketo](http://developers.marketo.com/javascript-api/forms/api-reference/) I am looking to listen to form submit event , The aforementioned form will also come from Marketo embed code

Comment: wrap it in a `async` `await` function?

Comment: async await for ? Could you please explain more?

Comment: you're waiting for an api, so you could use the async await keyword, to make sure, that you fetch the data, only after it's loaded

Comment: or you could do it in `componentDidMount`

Comment: form.onSuccess is triggered when the Form is submitted , the form is also rendered with embed code . I tried adding it to componentDidMount but it didn't worked i.e. on form submit the code within the onSuccess API handler didn't triggered anything

Comment: I don't think it's good practise to add `event Listener` in your jsx code.

Comment: instead what you could do is, add a `eventHandler` on your form, that would trigger, when the user submits the form, and in your handle, you could make a request, yo your api.

Comment: I dont need to make request to the API its an embed code I can just listen to the onSubmit event and than on basis of the returned value I was expecting to update the component state